# Commiting FragmentTransaction in 1 Tab of a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, fragmenttransaction, android-nested-fragment

I'm using `FragmentPageAdapter` to have multiple tabs within my app. 1 of those tabs is a `ListFragment` that is supposed to be replaced by another fragment `onItemClick`, using `FragmentTransaction`.

The change replace works perfectly if I add the `ListFragment` to a `FrameLayout` inside an `Activity`, but I'm not sure how to do this using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Here's a better explanation:

```
  Tab1       Tab2        Tab3        Tab4
fragment    fragment    fragment    fragment
subclass    subclass    subclass    listview
```

after clicking on one item from the fragment listview it should be replaced like this

```
  Tab1       Tab2        Tab3        Tab4
fragment    fragment    fragment    fragment
subclass    subclass    subclass    another-one
```

I tried using `.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), newFragment).commit()`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: yep, haven't solved this yet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll just drop this idea and change to use `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know it's always going to replace the `Fragment` on that *page*, then why not use a child `Fragment`?

Instead of using `getFragmentManager()` you use `getChildFragmentManager()` and put the `FrameLayout` at the top of the layout that you're using for the `Fragment`.

Comment: it's not quite what I needed. I'm not using a FrameLayout, but instead the fragments are managed by a FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: That makes no difference. Put a `FrameLayout` as a view in your `Fragment` layouts.

Comment: You mean that the 4th Tab contains a fragment with a FrameLayout, and inside that FrameLayout, I put my 2 fragments that I want to switch between to?

Comment: No, in the layout that you use in `onCreateView`, put a `FrameLayout` at the "top" that can be used for the `FragmentTransaction`. If you show me the layout you're using for the `Fragments`, themselves, I can show you exactly what I mean.